# Обратиться к php коду через js

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, функции

Есть небольшой фрагмент кода JavaScript и в нем мне нужно брать данные из базы данных через PHP. Как это сделать?
Советовали сделать через AJAX. Прошу привести пример по моему коду.

```
<script>
function sl(lt){
        var tb1 = <? echo($arr_t[0]) ?>; // Тут я засовываю в переменную tb1 элемент массива из php кода который написал в функции до этого фрагмента кода
        document.getElementById('location_button_1').onclick = () => sp(tb1);// вызываю другую функцию js
    }
function sp(lp){
    // А вот именно тут мне нужно обратиться к бд из php. Получить запись по id, а id это число, которое приняла эта функция в параметры, т.е lp
    var a = <? echo($asd) ?>; // Приравниваю этой переменной  значение которое я получил из бд
    sl(f); //И снова вызываю первую функцию. И так по кругу..
}
</script>
```

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, как все работает. Сначала отрабатывает php код на стороне сервера, полностью, до конца, он формирует страницу и отдает в том числе и текст javascript. Либо это может быть вообще отдельный php, который запускается, формирует нужное значение и опять же полностью завершается. Только после этого, уже в браузере пользователя начинает работать javascript. JS может сделать ajax вызов, в результате которого _новый запрос_ будет передан на сервер, там запустится с нуля php скрипт который может сформировать конкретный ответ и он вернется в JS, php на этом опять же завершится

Comment: Сначала у меня идет ход на этой же станице, php. Потом идет этот скрипт который запускается после него

Comment: Мне кажется автор немного путает пидали. На клиентской стороне нет php. Он только на сервере. Идёт запрос к серверу сервер обрабатывает запрос и отправляет ответ. Так вот у тебя должен быть ендпоинт на сервере который сделает запрос к базе и отправит ответ клиенту

Comment: Таким образом, если вы хотите брать элементы из некого массива php по очереди, то вам надо будет как минимум этот массив куда то сохранить на сервере так, что бы отдельный вызов php скрипта мог взять от туда одно значение и запомнить до следующего вызова на чем он остановился. Сохранять можно в чем угодно, в сессии, в обычной БД, в Redis. И каждый вызов из js php кода это дорогая операция - потому что это новое обращение по сети и запуск нового процесса на сервере. Исходя из этого надо бы пересмотреть логику приложения, например отдать весь массив заранее, за один вызов

Comment: Как это можно реализовать? Можете привести пример? пожалуйста

Comment: А так то никаких проблем конечно нет, если у вас есть например jquery на странице, то первая функция будет выглядеть буквально `$.ajax('url.php?параметры', {success: function(tb1) { document.getElementById.... }})` или аналог этого с использованием какой либо другой обертки ajax или непосредственно xmlhttprequest. соответственно url.php из этого вызова должен будет при одном вызове возвращать единственноеm, очередное значение для tb1 (например полный текст файла url.php: `<?php echo 5; ?>`)

Comment: Привести пример чего ? сначала вы должны определиться, уже зная как все работает, по какому пути вы хотите идти. Спланировать какие отдельные вызовы хотели бы отправлять на сервер и какие данные и в каком объеме получать

Comment: Начните с того, что определитесь, готовы ли вы сразу, при формировании страницы создать весь массив (и может еще какие доп значения) целиком. Если да - то ajax вам не нужен, печатайте на страницу сразу массив: `var arr=[1,5,9,15,20]; function sl(lt) { ... arr.pop(); // получаем очередное значение из массива }`. Если нет - тогда да, ajax. решайте какими порциями готовы отдавать данные

Answer (score 0):

Логика конечно хромает, будет работать медленно.
Примерно так:

1. Берем наш lp, и отправляем его через ajax в PHP ajax.php, get или post запросом
2. В ajax.php получаем этот запрос и отправляемся в php кодом запрос в бд, SELECT id2 FROM TABLE WHERE id=$_GET['lp'], в ответ получим переменную id2
3. По ajax она прилетает назад в переменной f.
4. Далее по кругу.

По идее лучше сразу js собрать все данные со страницы и обработать из через php-бд, и уже готовыми данными работать, которые например в виде массива будут уже храниться.

Comment: из вопроса "... кое какие данные из базы данных через php ...". А судя по сложности вопроса - это начинающий программист и вряд ли используем что-то кроме mysql